# Two XSL files need single final output file

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a input file and two XSL files test1.xsl, test2.xsl

1. test1.xsl file transforming on input file and generating test1-output.xml
2. test2.xsl file transforming on test1-output.xml and generating the final output

**Requirement:**

I am using XSLT 2.0
I want run at a time both xslt files transform on input file and generate the final output.
How to do this requirement, Please suggest!

**Input file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<k>
    <page>content here</page>
    <page1>content here</page1>
</k>
```

**test1.xsl file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"qqq encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmqlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*| node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="page">
        <page>
            <kita>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </kita>
        </page>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output of test1.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<k>
    <page>
      <kita>content here</kita>
   </page>
    <page1>content here</page1>
</k>
```

**test2.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*| node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="kita">
        <kita>
            <kita1>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </kita1>
        </kita>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This is my final xml output from the 2nd XSLT file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<k>
    <page>
      <kita>
         <kita1>content here</kita1>
      </kita>
   </page>
    <page1>content here</page1>
</k>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do want to know how to initiate the xsl? What xslt-processor are you using. Btw, your 2 transformations can be done by using just 1 xslt and a extra mode.

Comment: Hi @sibe: I know we can do in single xslt for this example. But I want to know how to do above requirements. Please suggest

Comment: Ok, but then which  xslt-processor are you using?

Comment: And on what platform, using which language?

Comment: XPath 3 available in XSLT 3 has a `transform` function you can use if you have an XSLT 3 processsor like Saxon 9.8 or later, Saxon-JS 2 or AltovaXML 2017 R3 and later. A general solution based on an XSLT 2 processor would probably need to look into a host language like XProc or of course Java or C# or a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3 you could write a stylesheet with two parameters calling `fn:transform` twice e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="xslt1" as="document-node()"/>
<xsl:param name="xslt2" as="document-node()"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence
    select="
    transform(map {
      'stylesheet-node' : $xslt1,
      'source-node' : .
    })?output ! transform(map {
      'stylesheet-node' : $xslt2,
      'source-node' : .
    })?output"/>
</xsl:template>
```

or if you want to pass in the file URIs

```
<xsl:param name="xslt1" as="xs:string">test1.xsl</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="xslt2" as="xs:string">test2.xsl</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence
    select="
    transform(map {
      'stylesheet-node' : doc($xslt1),
      'source-node' : .
    })?output ! transform(map {
      'stylesheet-node' : doc($xslt2),
      'source-node' : .
    })?output"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks @martin, but I am using xslt 2.0, then how to do in xslt 2.0

Comment: Sibe: I am not using any language just simply I am transforming one document to another document using oxygen editor

Comment: @KitaAnsari, I did only post the XSLT version as the newly introduced `fn:transform` function allows you to run XSLT from within XSLT so for that you need to move to XSLT 3 or you need to look into processor specific extensions or, as said in a comment, look outside of XSLT into XProc, Java, C# or any host language allowing you to chain XSLT transformations.